# Trigger jenkins Job with Azure AD Auth

Tags: jenkins, curl, cmd, azure-active-directory, windows-scripting

I have integrated Jenkins with Azure AD and it is working fine without any issue. Now I want to trigger the jenkins job remotely. Previously I was using the jenkins username and password with `curl`, and it was working fine, but now I'm using my Azure AD mail id, and jenkins token, it is not working.

```bash
curl -X POST https://{name}.{org name}.com/job/[job name]/build --user jenkins_user:jenkins_user_token
```

Kindly help on how to do this with Azure AD Auth.

Which command need to be used to trigger the jenkins job which is integrated with Azure AD?

Is it possible to create using script?